# Is it a vector or scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_p)$ and $a_1=(a_{11}, a_{21},...,a_{p1})$.

What is $z_1=a_{1}^TX$? Obviously it's a square matrix. However, in the text I'm reading it says $z_1=a_{1}^TX=\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i1}x_i$. The summation gives a single number, so what exactly is $z_1$? Matrix or scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, $X$ and $a_1$ should both be vectors in $\mathbb R^p$. Then they are usually written as columns.
$$X = (x_1, \ldots, x_p)^T, a_1 = (a_{11}, \ldots, a_{p1})^T$$
And $z_1 = a_1^T X$ is their inner product (a scalar).

If on the other hand $a_1$ and $X$ are rows (as you wrote it down),
$$z_1 = a_1^T X \in \mathbb R^{p\times p}$$
is a rank-1 square matrix.
A little side note: The trace of this matrix is the inner product from above.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know the matrix is rank-1 in the second case?

Comment: @user4205580 All its rows / columns are multiples of the same vector ($X$ / $a_1$ resp.). Thus (unless one of the vectors is the zero-vector) the rank is $1$. If one of them is $0\in\mathbb R^p$, the rank will of course be $0$.

Comment: I was referring to the page 6 of [this document](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/statistics_refs/PrincipalComponentAnalysis.pdf). I think the notation is weird-the last line says that we want to calculate variance of $z_1$. How can you calculate variance of a single number? I have no idea how to understand it.

Comment: @user4205580 In that document, $X$ is a vector of random variables. I suggest you ask a follow-up question if that doesn't make it clear enough.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a vector of random variables. But the result $z_1$ is just a single number.

Comment: @user4205580 No, the result is a (scalar) random variable.

Comment: In this example we have $p$ different types of measurements. We want to find the direction in which, given $n$ set of $p$ measurements, the points in $R^p$ will vary the most.

Comment: Yeah somewhat..

Comment: We can treat $z_1=a_{1}^{T}x$ as a function of a vector of random variables. And this is the reason you call $z_1$, the value of this function, a random variable? Or for some other reason?

Comment: @user4205580 Yes, it _is_ a random variable because of its definition (a transformation of RVs is a RV)